# in opencv facedetaction project found that error in my code so plss help me

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection

```
07-03 16:26:27.435: E/AndroidRuntime(6838): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 16:26:27.435: E/AndroidRuntime(6838): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load detection_based_tracker from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.opencv.samples.facedetect-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.opencv.samples.facedetect-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null

07-03 16:26:27.435: E/AndroidRuntime(6838):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
07-03 16:26:27.435: E/AndroidRuntime(6838):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:514)
07-03 16:26:27.435: E/AndroidRuntime(6838):     at org.opencv.samples.facedetect.FdActivity$1.onManagerConnected(FdActivity.java:66)
07-03 16:26:27.435: E/AndroidRuntime(6838):     at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper$1.onServiceConnected(AsyncServiceHelper.java:318)
07-03 16:26:27.435: E/AndroidRuntime(6838):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1131)
07-03 16:26:27.435: E/AndroidRuntime(6838):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1148)
07-03 16:26:27.435: E/AndroidRuntime(6838):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
07-03 16:26:27.435: E/AndroidRuntime(6838):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
07-03 16:26:27.435: E/AndroidRuntime(6838):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
07-03 16:26:27.435: E/AndroidRuntime(6838):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
07-03 16:26:27.435: E/AndroidRuntime(6838):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 16:26:27.435: E/AndroidRuntime(6838):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-03 16:26:27.435: E/AndroidRuntime(6838):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
07-03 16:26:27.435: E/AndroidRuntime(6838):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-03 16:26:27.435: E/AndroidRuntime(6838):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: did you convert it to C/C++ Project?

Comment: no not convert in c/c++ project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (on Eclipse):

1. Right click on the project and select New -> Other.
2. In C/C++ folder select "Convert to a C/C++ Project(Adds C/C++ Nature).

You see it here: 
[Tron Academy Episode 2: Setting Up Android NDK and OpenCV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2onPuDZQVY)  (You can start watch in 8:30 minutes.)